# How to use ajax to verify and submit a form on successful verification?

Tags: jquery, ajax, captcha

I am trying to submit a form after its captcha check. I am using the [Securimage](https://www.phpcaptcha.org/) module as the captcha module.

I am trying verify and submit the form using `onsubmit` method and using ajax call to verify the captcha. I can check but unable to submit on successful captcha check.

Here is my jquery function:

```
function processForm()
    {
        var captcha = $("#captcha_code1").val();
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: 'resources/qform/captcha_check.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {captcha_code: captcha},
            dataType: 'json'
        }).done(function(data) {
            if (data.error === 0){
                alert('submit successful');
                return true;
            }else{
                alert("There was an error with your submission.\n\n" + data.message);
                jQuery('#captcha_code1').val('');
                return false;
            }
        });

        return false;
    }
```

The above code returns 'submit successful' alert on successful chptcha check but unable to submit form. So, Is it possible to do the both and if yes, then how?

Answer (score 1):

jQuery.ajax is asynchronous, hence onsubmit handler returns false in order to prevent form submission.

That's correct. Now , when you get **data.error** you need to rise the submit event by yourself. I may suggest to pass the form element as a parameter in order to trigger the submit:

```
HTMLFormElement.submit()
```

The submit() call does not trigger again your function as reported in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit).

Comment: I tried to submit the form using `$('form#type-1').submit();`. But its not submitting any data to the action page. Can you please help with that.

Comment: @ArijitPanda I'm sorry. I was not enough clear. I suggested to use the plain javascript. While the jQuery **$('form#type-1').submit();** trigger the submit event the plain javascript does not raise again the event: **document.querySelector('form#type-1').submit();** and so your code does not run again your **processForm**